# SQL advanced query counting the max value of a group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to create a query that will count the number of times the following condition is met.

I have a table that consists of multiple records with a matching foreign key. I want to check only for each of the foreign key groups if the highest value of another column of that key occurs more than once. If it does that will up the count.

Data

```
--------------------------
ID  |  Foreign Key | Value
--------------------------
1   |       1      |   1
2   |       1      |   2 
3   |       1      |   2
4   |       2      |   0
5   |       2      |   2
6   |       2      |   1
7   |       3      |   0
8   |       3      |   1
9   |       3      |   1
```

The query I want should return the number 2. This is because the maximum value in group 1(Foreign Key) occurs twice, the value is 2. In group 2 the maximum value is 2 but only occurs once so this will not up the count. Then in group 3 the maximum value is 1 which occurs twice which will up the count. The count therefore ends up as two.

Comment: Just looking for a point in the correct direction not a complete answer

Comment: This would do it in oracle - you can get some ideas from it: select count(1) from (select distinct fk from (select fk, count(1) from d where (fk, val) in (select fk, max(val) from d group by fk) group by fk having count(1) > 1));

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to the comment from @Bob, but here is the sql that solved this problem.

```
SELECT Count(1) 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT foreign_key 
    FROM   (SELECT foreign_key, 
                   Count(1) 
            FROM   data 
            WHERE  ( foreign_key, value ) IN (SELECT foreign_key, 
                                                     Max(value) 
                                              FROM   data 
                                              GROUP  BY foreign_key) 
            GROUP  BY foreign_key 
            HAVING Count(1) > 1) AS data) AS data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```
select max(num_at_max)
  from (select t.*, count(val) over(partition by fk) as num_at_max
          from tbl t
          join (select max(max_val_by_grp) as max_val_all_grps
                 from (select fk, max(val) as max_val_by_grp
                         from tbl
                        group by fk) x) x
            on t.val = x.max_val_all_grps) x
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this answer, I have answered above with the solution I used for this problem. I am in no way advanced in SQL, what are the differences between these two answers I should consider?

Comment: They should be functionally the same in that they should always return the same result, however the execution plan may be more advantageous one way or the other. It is hard to say which would run better for you because it depends on the actual table's whole data, how it's indexed, among other factors. Testing in Oracle my answer versus the previous answer the plan appears similar other than a trade between a hash group by (other answer) and nested loops (my answer). It is hard to say how both will actually process in your real database with the full actual data. I'd use whichever is faster.